# How to give same style to first 2 paragraphs differently in css

Tags: css

How to give same style to first 2 paragraphs differently in css.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
p+p {color:red}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>first paragraph</p>
  <p>second paragraph</p>
  <p>third paragraph</p>
  <p>fourth paragraph</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

I've tried this but it's leaving first paragraph and styling all other.

and this only style first paragraph not others

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
p:first-child { color: blue; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>first paragraph</p>
  <p>second paragraph</p>
  <p>third paragraph</p>
  <p>fourth paragraph</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

remember I want to give same style on first 2 paragraph.

Comment: Giving multiple elements the same ID defeats the entire purpose of giving them any ID at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go here, and try this code out :)

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_first-child1

```
p:first-child
{
    color:blue;
} 
p:first-child + p
{
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: I hope your kidding ... I intentionally made the second one red and the first one blue to show you which of the above CSS selectors was affecting which paragraph tag.

Make the second one say "blue" instead of "red".

Comment: oh, sorry yes u are right. it's working . thanks. can u tell what is the solution if i want to style like first 3 <p> or first 4 <p>.

Comment: @Jitendra - try adding + p to the *p:first-child + p* for each additional p you want to style. (You also need a new set of curly braces and rules.)

Comment: @Moshe - Thnaks. it's working - p:first-child, p:first-child + p, p:first-child + p + p
{color:blue;}

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what browsers you want to be compatible with. The latest versions of Firefox, Safari, Chrome, and Opera all support the [`nth-of-type` pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo), but IE does not yet (it is a CSS 3 feature, which IE does not support much of). If you can limit yourself to these browsers, the following should work, otherwise, you'll need to use one of the solutions from one of the other answers.

```
p:nth-of-type(1), p:nth-of-type(2) { color: red }
```

Comment: Nice tut, but CSS3 is not widely supported enough. Ah well, +1 anyways for the interesting lesson ni CSS3

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that CSS3 isn't widely supported enough. I wanted to document this solution for the future, or for people who are targeting only a dingle platform, even though it's impractical for the web as a whole right now.

Answer (score 2):

first of all, ID's need to be unique on a page. You can't use id="hello" twice. You need to use *class* for that. Try:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
.hello { color: blue; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <p class="hello">first paragraph</p>
  <p class="hello">second paragraph</p>
  <p>third paragraph</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: id removed it was added mistakenly